# Using setInterval in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading the tutorial on the official react website. In the example about life cycle methods, under the componentDidMount method, a timerID is set to the setInterval function.

My question is even though the timerID was initialized, it was never called throughout the application, how does the application work without explicitly calling timerID anywhere in the application. Here is the code below.

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')

);
```

Comment: Your link is not working.

Comment: @KyleRichardson sorry for the inconvenience, I have now included the code in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this.timerID` is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to `setInterval()`; this value can be passed to `clearInterval` to clear the timer.

So when calling the setInterval in componentDidMount like

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }
```

you want to execute the `tick()` function `every 1 sec a`fter the component has mounted. Now when you navigate to another component and your current component has unmounted, if you **do not clear the interval** call to `tick()` function, it will continue to be executed.

Hence in the `componentWillUnmount` function you timer is cleared which is identified by the numeric value returned by `setInterval` which is stored in `this.timerID`

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }
```

so the complete code as provided in the React docs is

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple. As soon as it React executes **componentDidMount()** life cycle method, the timer starts running.

```
this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
```

The above timer will run until the component gets unmounted (according to your code). It's not a surprise that your code works that way.

Answer (score 0):

In this react document it's written that

> We will tear down the timer in the componentWillUnmount() lifecycle
>   method

So, `this.timerID` will be used in `componentWillUnmount()` lifecycle method to stop timer.