# setInterval being called at an ever increasing rate in a React component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

If I call setInterval in a React component it works as expected, the `console.log` fires every second:

```
function Component() {
  setInterval(() => {
    console.log("1");
  }, 1000);
  return (
    // Stuff
  )
```

However when I use `setInterval` to change a value in the Redux store, and I also use that value as prop in the same component, then `increment` appears to be being called at an ever increasing rate:

```
function Component({
  increment,
  numerChangedByIncrement
}) {
  setInterval(() => {
    increment()
  }, 1000);
  return (
    <h1>{numerChangedByIncrement}</h1>
  )
```

I believe this is because when the `numerChangedByIncrement` prop changes the component re-renders, creating another `setInterval`. Is this correct?

If so then is there a best practice way to solve this? I can think of a few approaches:

1) Move `setInterval` into it's own component that doesn't have the `increment` prop as this will stop it re-rendering. However will I have the same issue if a parent re-renders? As presumably this will also re-render the component housing `setInterval`?

2) Use `setTimeout` instead, although this feels hacky. Also would the timer be slightly inaccurate as the time would be 1000ms + the time taken to re-render the component?

3) Clean up `setInterval` when the component dismounts.

4) Move `setInterval` to the Redux file so it's not within React at all.

I found a similar question here but it uses classes lifecycle methods which is not the latest API (using Hooks etc): 
[Using setInterval in React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158087/using-setinterval-in-react-component)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timers in `React` [always have been a problem](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/). To declare imperative code in React do it inside `useEffect` or lifecycle hooks. The following is a straightforward implementation of a timer

```
const UpdateEvery2Seconds = () =>{
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    useEffect(() =>{
        const interval = setInterval(() => setCounter(counter + 1), 2000)

        //Cleaning it up
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    },[])

    return <div>{counter}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use  useEffect in react it looks like what you want

```
import {useState,useEffect} from'react'
    function sameruleSetintervale(){
        const [numberTimer,setNumberTimer]=useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => setNumberTimer(numberTimer + 1), 1000)

    }, [])

    return <h1>{numberTimer}</h1>}
```